# React giving error when used connect function to provide state to Hoc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hi everyone  I want to use a **withAuth HOC** to decide whether the homePage should be rendered as dashboard or a guest HomePage. Further i want to use this logic with other components to.
But i am stuck with error whenever i try to connect my hoc using map state to props it returns

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

img :-

[image: ERROR IMAGE]

. I **saw other similar stackOverflow solutions** **but none of them could clear my error.**

I tried to use compose also but even that didn't worked out.If i remove the connect it works like charm.But i would need redux state in my hoc. Also i thought of using hooks of react-redux but i just want to keep things simple for now.

**Main.js**

```
// this file is responsible for handling routes logic 
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Switch , withRouter, Route,useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from '../components/Home'
import Auth from '../components/Auth'
import authUser from '../stores/action/auth'
import {clearError} from '../stores/action/error'
import WithAuth from '../hocs/withAuth'


function Main(props){
   let location=useLocation();
    let clearError=props.clearError
    let {error,currentUser}={props}
   useEffect(()=>{

   },[location.pathname,currentUser])



   const NewComponent=WithAuth(Home);
    return(
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" >
                <NewComponent />    
            </Route>


            <Route exact path="/signUp">
                 <Auth heading={"Welcome to warbler"} isAuthenticated={props.currentUser.isAuthenticated} error={props.error} signUp={true} buttonText="Sign Up" />
            </Route> 
            <Route exact path="/login">
                 <Auth authUser={props.authUser} isAuthenticated={props.currentUser.isAuthenticated} error={props.error} signUp={false} heading={"Welcome Back :)"} buttonText="Log In" />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    )
}




function mapStateToProps(state){
    return (
        {
          ...state
        }
    )
}


export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,{authUser,clearError})(Main))
```

WithAuth.js

```
import React , {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
function WithAuth(Comp){
    return class  extends React.Component{

        render(){

                    if(this.props.isAuthenticated){
                        return (<div>Sucess!</div>)
                    }
                    else{
                        return (
                            <Comp {...this.props} />
                    ) 

                    }


        }
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return({
        isAuthenticated:state.currentUser.isAuthenticated
    }
    )
}

 export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(WithAuth)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured out the mistake. This is what i did wrong:-->

I somehow assumed that HOC itself is a component type and that's why i was mapping my connect with HOC it self. But what i found is that hoc is simply a function returns the component which in my case was the class that i was returning.

> **So i should have mapped my class Component with state rather then the HOC component itself.**

Thats why i suppouse the connect was giving problem. Thought i can't say that  this was the exact reason but it definitely solved the problem. Also for those who are familiar with redux hooks api we can use  the --**useSelector()** at here though the reason why i was avoiding it was because it was a lot of re-rendering.

Here's the correct code for **HOC**

```
import React , {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

 function WithAuth(Comp){
     class HOC extends React.Component{

    render(){

                if(this.props.isAuthenticated){
                    return (<div>Sucess!</div>)
                }
                else{
                    return (
                        <Comp {...this.props} />
                ) 

                }


    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return(
        {
        isAuthenticated:state.currentUser.isAuthenticated
    }
    )
}

// **RETURN SHOULD BE INSIDE HOC**
return connect(mapStateToProps,null)(HOC)


}

export default WithAuth
```

Comment: This is the article that i referred :-->https://code.likeagirl.io/how-to-create-a-connected-hoc-with-react-and-redux-8631f7b1497